Track origin of access to a static webpage with AWSTATS?
I made a simple one-page website for my wife's small business by modifying a template. But I am pretty much a noob.
Anyway, we have an iframe on the page that points to an external provider for reservations to the business.
For this reason, we would very much like to know which sources drive most traffic to the website, so we can focus on those. As it happens, I can see in AWSTATS that by far the most traffic comes from people who access the address directly, which means they scan one of the QR codes that we've placed in a few places.
However, I would like to have a better picture of that. So, for example, let's say I make the QR code on the business cards point to link1, a QR code from the shield on the building points to link2 etc...
And then, when I look in AWSTATS, I see who accessed the website from link1, who from link2 etc.
I was thinking of adding something like ?source=business_cards, ?source=shield at the end of the links. But I can't see that AWSTATS cares about that. Or, at least, I don't know how to make it work. Because, I do wonder how it manages to know accesses incoming from google, or facebook - I think the mechanism is similar.
Another idea I have is to make symlinks to index.html and have each QR code point to a different one. AWSTATS shows me which files were accessed. But this feels a bit wonky.
